# PyGtk with Gtk+3 gives illegal instruction 4

Tags: pygtk

I'm on macOS Ventura with Python3. I'm trying to setup the system for PyGtk development. I installed home-brew and gtk+3 3.24.38 and pygobject3 3.44.1. When I run the following sample "hello world", I get an Illegal Instruction: 4. I know what illegal instruction 4 means, but I have no idea what is going wrong. AFAIK, I have installed all the right packages. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had MacPorts as well as Home-brew installed on my system. I had installed Gtk+3 on both of them. I uninstalled both, installed only Home-brew with Gtk+3 and PyGObject3. After that the sample program works fine.